# NotFoundException in layout editor for Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm trying to extend a RelativeLayout object and include an embedded SurfaceView object that uses a png file in my /res/drawable folder as its background but I keep getting an error in the XML Layout editor. See the following code:

```
public class StopMotionRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout
{
    private Context myContext;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView1;

    private BitmapFactory.Options myBitmapOptions;
    private final android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = 
        new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    public StopMotionRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        myContext = context;
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        //init images
        surfaceView1 = new SurfaceView(myContext,attrs);
        surfaceView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        this.addView(surfaceView1, params);

    }

        @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        myBitmapOptions = new Options();
        myBitmapOptions.outWidth = widthMeasureSpec;
        myBitmapOptions.outHeight = heightMeasureSpec;

        surfaceView1.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.myContext.getResources(),
                R.drawable.golf1, myBitmapOptions)));
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> NotFoundException: Could not find
>   drawable resource matching value
>   0x7F020002 (resolved name: golf1) in
>   current configuration.

I have seen this type of error may times now and it always happens when I try to load something from a resource file via code and not XML. Curiously, this error does not stop me from compiling the app, and the app runs without error in the emulator. I'd like to get back the use of my layout editor though...

Please help.

**UPDATE:** Here is the layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.games.test.StopMotionRelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</com.games.test.StopMotionRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: For completeness, would you mind posting the layout XML?

Comment: Do you have your golf1.png in the folder /res/drawable-[h|m|l]dpi that matches to your emulatror's / device's configuration? When using a decoder, it might be crucial that you have the resource in the correct folder, since you are going to deal with it, not let the default scale or crop to take place.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it would work if you specified a value for android:background in the XML and then override it in your code.

As a workaround, you could also try calling the isInEditMode() function and not set the background in edit mode.